# Python - print string to a file

Tags: python

When I use print function in Python like this

```
print (', '.join(mlink), file=mylist)
```

then `mylist` is

```
file1,flie2,file3
```

How can I change the above print function to have the whole thing inside ( ) and each file enclosed by '' like this

```
('file1','file2','file3')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: unrelated: the first line could be written as `print(*mlink, sep=', ', file=mylist)` (if it is OK to accept non-string items). btw, `mylist`, `mlink` are not very evocative names for a file and a sequence objects correspondingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(repr(tuple(mlink)), file=mylist)
```

Demo:

```
In [251]: mlink = ['file1','file2','file3']

In [252]: repr(tuple(mlink))
Out[252]: "('file1', 'file2', 'file3')"

In [253]: print(repr(tuple(mlink)), file=open('mylist', 'wb'))
```

produces a file called `mylist` which contains:

```
('file1', 'file2', 'file3')
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks. Sorry, forgot to mention that I use while loop for multiple pages, the above code give me ('file1_1','file1_2,'file1_3')('file2_1','file2_2','file2_3')('file3_1','file3_2,'file3_3') How can I have an output like ('file1_1','file1_2,'file1_3','file2_1','file2_2','file2_3','file3_1','file3_2,'file3_3') Thank you.